# How to check the username and password using MySql Data source in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am new on asp.net.
i want to know how to check my username and password by using MYSQL...
i use the following code behing my .cs file

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=dbabc;Uid=root;Pwd=;");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            Response.Write("MySQL conenct successfully");

        }
        catch (MySqlException error)
        {
            Response.Write("MySQL could not be connect to the server try agian!");
        }

    }
    protected void signin_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i=0;
        string sql = "SELECT username, password from login where username='" + username_tb + "' and password = '" + password_tb + "'" ;
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.Read())
        {
            result.InnerText = rdr[0].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            result.InnerText = "Sorry record Not found!";
        }


        conn.Close();
    }
```

and these are the following code in index.aspx

```
Username : <input type="text" id="username_tb" name="username_tb" style="weight:250px; height: 25px;" runat="server"></input><br />
Password : <input type="password" id="password_tb" name="password_tb" style="weight:250px; height:25px;" runat="server"></input><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Signin" style="weight:30px; height:25px; margin-top: 3px;" runat="server" onserverclick="signin_btn_Click"></input><br />

</div>
<label id="result" runat="server"></label>
```

so finally i need to say that i want a result which says username and password are correct in case of sucess and username and password was not correct in case of failure

Comment: What exactly is your question? Or are you just asking us to write code for you?

Comment: yes.
i want to know how to use SELECT command and return a string "Username and password is correcr" or "username and password is incorrect"...

Comment: or you can edit a command of MySQL in my given script as well...

Comment: my code work fine. but the problem is that whether i type coreect username and password.. it always give a "Sorry record Not found!"

which exist in else{ result.InnerText = "Sorry record Not found!"; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `username_tb` and `password_tb` are TextBox controls? In that case, you need to refer to the `.Text` inside of them, not to the controls themselves. Try changing your sql string to this:

```
string sql = "SELECT username, password from login where username='" + username_tb.Text + "' and password = '" + password_tb.Text + "'" ;
```

There's a lot of other problems with your code (like it being very susceptible to SQL injection attacks), but I won't try to correct them all here.

Comment: Yes i got my error...
but one thing i mention at here that .text is written with asp textbox field. i use .value with my textbox.. thanks...

Answer (score 1):

How to check the username and password using a Sql data source in ASP.NET:

```
protected void btsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
     string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["remCoString"].ConnectionString;
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr);
     conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Username, Password from login where Username='" + usertxt.Text + "' and Password = '" + passtxt.Text + "'", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", usertxt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", passtxt.Text);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {        
        Response.Redirect("Details.aspx");
    }
    else
    {    
        msg.Text = "user name and password are wrong";     
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```